# How to drag a widget and click on it at the same time in tkinter ??? In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind, drag

Does anyone know an event for saying "when the element is grabbed" by grab I mean not just pressed or clicked but when we try to move an element from one position to another (it's more like drag the element)

For example I want to do two things at the same time on a widget (a Label) when I click on it, it display other labels (2 others) and when I grab it => I can move it

The initial line to lunch an event when the mouse is clicked is :

```
widget.bind('<Button-1>', function)
```

How I can click and drag a widget at the same time ??? There's a event to do that ?

**The full code you don't necessarily have to read it :**

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.resizable(False,False)
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=1,fill=BOTH)



label = tk.Label(frame,text='˃LABEL',fg='green')
label.grid(column=0,row=0)


label2 = Label(frame,text='˃LABEL2',fg='green')
label3 = Label(frame,text='˃LABEL3',fg='green')

def change(event):
    
    label['text'] = '˅LABEL'
    label2.grid(column=0,row=1)
    label3.grid(column=0,row=2)
    widget = event.widget
    widget._drag_start_x = event.x
    widget._drag_start_y = event.y
    if label['text'] == '˅LABEL':
        label.bind('<Button-1>', hide)

def hide(event):
    label['text'] = '˃LABEL'
    label2.grid_forget()
    label3.grid_forget()
    if label['text'] == '˃LABEL':
        label.bind('<Button-1>',change)
        
label.bind('<Button-1>',change)

def make_draggable(widget):
    widget.bind("<Button-1>", change)
    widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)

#def on_drag_start(event):
    
    

def on_drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_start_x + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_start_y + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)

make_draggable(label)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm blocked like 3 days on it I can't find an answer :(

Comment: There's a bug I have the slight impression that you can't do both at the same time...

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think you need to do either of two things: 1. update the position of the sub labels (label2, label3...) so that they follow the original position when the main one is moved. 2. hide the sub labels whenever you drag them around, then either show them right under the main label, or update it as (1.) does.

Comment: use a Canvas: a working example is part of my rapidTk module: https://github.com/AceScottie/RapidTk/blob/main/rapidTk/cWidgets_extended.py#L262